# React Form Submit to MTurk

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a React onclick method which is supposed to set up a form to submit to MTurk.
It should be setting up an input field of text, with name 'assignmentId', and a fake hardcoded string value, attaching it to a POST form, and (although currently commented out) submit the form.

```
  const handleSurveyClick = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const form      = document.createElement('form')
    form.action = (new URL('mturk/externalSubmit', urlParams.get('turkSubmitTo'))).href
    form.method = 'post'

    const inputAssignmentId = document.createElement('input')
    inputAssignmentId.type  = 'text'
    inputAssignmentId.name  = 'assignmentId'
    inputAssignmentId.value = 'fake hardcoded number'
    form.appendChild(inputAssignmentId)

    document.body.appendChild(form)  // <------ See Below
//    form.submit()
  }
```

In chrome, when I inspect the console to see the form, here is what I get:

```
form: <form action=​"https:​/​/​workersandbox.mturk.com/​mturk/​externalSubmit" method=​"post">
​  <input type=​"text" name=​"assignmentId">
​</form>​
```

Critically, there is no value field in that input field.
Weirdly, when the `document.body.appendChild(form)` line executes, the fake hardcoded number gets displayed on the web page I'm trying to submit the form from.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not to be prescriptive, but your current solution doesn't leverage the declarative features of React very much, so I want to start there. React is a declarative front end library, if you want to code imperatively and add nodes to the DOM yourself, your better off just using vanilla Javascript. Adding nodes to the DOM yourself when using React can often have some interesting effects, which makes your question of, "What am I doing wrong" hard to answer other than to say, you're code is a bit counter intuitive for React.

If I was to change your solution in a way that works, and takes advantage of React's features, this is what I'd do:

Set up a `SurveyForm` component:

```
// survey-form.jsx
import React from 'react';

const SurveyForm = ({ urlParams, action }) => {
  return (
    <form method='post' action={action}>
      <input type='text' name='assignmentId' defaultValue='fake hardcoded number' />
      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I'd then conditionally render your `SurveyForm` in the desired manner whenever a survey was clicked. [Docs on conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

When you render it you'll have to give it the corresponding props I made use of within the component.

Comment: I promise you, the rest of the project uses react extensively.  But I'm trying to understand what's going wrong with that specific piece of code.

Comment: I just think it's really hard to say what might be happening because of the fact the nodes are being manually appended to the DOM. If I were to guess, React is wiping out the value of the input on a subsequent render.

Comment: Apologies for any pretense that React was not being uses declaratively in the rest of the project, my comments were purely towards the one piece of code I can see here.

Comment: Understood-- I know that section of code is not very react-like, but mTurk is very finicky and I'm trying to go step by agonizingly slow step.